# Notification when a VSTS Request is created as unassigned

Tags: azure, azure-devops, workflow

I'm hoping to create an email notification for when a VSTS Request is 'created', or saved for the first time as unassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [a custom notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops) that send alert when the work item is created ("State" Changes from = " ") and it's unassigned ("Assigned" To = " "):

[image]